# Cocos2d: how to share player data between scenes

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, singleton

**I got a PlayerData class deriving from CCNode and I would like to share it between the various scenes of the game as static singleton instance.**

I have tried the following implementation:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
@interface PlayerData : CCNode {

}

@property (readwrite, nonatomic) int data;  
+(id) playerData;
+(PlayerData*) sharedPlayerData;

#import "PlayerData.h"
@implementation PlayerData
@synthesize data;
static PlayerData* instanceOfPlayerData;

+(id) playerData 
{
    if(instanceOfPlayerData==nil){
        return  [[self alloc] init];
    }else {
        return [self sharedPlayerData];
    }
}

+(PlayerData*) sharedPlayerData{
    NSAssert(instanceOfPlayerData != nil, @"PlayerData instance not yet initialized!");
    return instanceOfPlayerData;
}


-(id) init 
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        instanceOfPlayerData=self;
        data=0;
        }
    return self;
}
@end
```

**Where is the right place to allocate this?** I thought about adding and accessing it to the AppDelegate class but I cannot quiet understand how.

I see that from the sharedDirector I can access to a delagate value but I don't think is the right one unless I have to cast it to my AppDelegate class. Any suggestion?

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] delegate];
```

And this is my AppDelegate class as from template:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface AppController : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, CCDirectorDelegate>
{
    UIWindow *window_;
    UINavigationController *navController_;

    CCDirectorIOS   *__unsafe_unretained director_;                         // weak ref
}

@property (nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (readonly) UINavigationController *navController;
@property (unsafe_unretained, readonly) CCDirectorIOS *director;

@end
```

**PS: I am using Cocos2d v2.x with ARC enabled**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great singleton tutorial I used for my game and works great: http://getsetgames.com/2009/08/30/the-objective-c-singleton/

Comment: I definitely recommend this, but you could also just initialize your scene with all of the player data.

Comment: @Omega thanks, I did use the singleton pattern and I love it. I allocate the class in the AppDelegate and then access it where needed. Although, for cleaniness, I am thinking about loading it in a "loading scene" when starting the game so I don't "dirty" the app delegate with Game specific classes..

Comment: @mm24: Well, yeah, if there is something you don't need to hold globally, the singleton approach might not be necessary. But it is great for things like holding save file data - things you need to save in your game for later use like player level, stats, currency, playtime, etc... And you still can make your code rather clean. Perhaps put all player-specific data in an NSDictionary within the singleton, etc.